# How to get fix size numbers from string array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new to Java. I have a string array like this,

```
String [] numArray = {"1234", "-1234" , "abcd", "12ab","2345","1a34"};
```

I want to get 4 digt positive numbers from this array.

> Expected Output : 1234 2345

Comment: post what you have done till now. this looks like an assignment.

Comment: Okay, so there are lots of different ways you could do this. Have you tried anything yet? Hint: first find the strings which consist of exactly 4 digits, and then parse them (assuming you need them as `int` values.)

Comment: one way can be : Iterate through array, try converting to number, if gets converted then check against 0 and print result

Comment: You can use Integer.parseInt() to parse an integer string. Be careful though because you'll get a NumberFormatException on the string that contain non numbers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this `Pattern`,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}"); 
String [] numArray = {"1234", "-1234" , "abcd", "12ab","2345","1a34"};

for(String num: numArray){
    if(pattern.matcher(num).matches()){
         System.out.print(num + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: He is new to Java. And you throw a regex at him, without any further explanation?

Comment: I really like this answer, i guess i am new to regex :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is very helpful for me

Answer (score -1):

We can also do it using `try-catch` block where we try to convert the string to Integer and if a `NumberFormatException` occurs then we `continue`.

```
    String[] numArray = {"1234", "-1234", "abcd", "12ab", "2345", "1a34"};
    for(String x : numArray){
       try{
           int val = Integer.parseInt(x);
           if(val >= 0 && x.length() == 4)
           System.out.print(val +" ");
       } catch(NumberFormatException n){
           continue;
       }
    }
```

Comment: He is interested only in 4 digit numbers. there is no check for that.